# TortoiseProc how to diff file between revisions from command line

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to open the diff command from the command line to see the differences between a file and its previous version. According to the docs i can be done with the diff argument. This would give me the difference between a file and the base revision, but did not work for me:

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

```
call TortoiseProc.exe /command:diff /path:%CD%\%1
```

To clarify, any one would know how to start from command line the "TortoiseSVN" that would be the equivalent of this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
call TortoiseProc.exe /command:prevdiff /path:%CD%\%1
```

you can find the commands very easily:
open the TortoiseSVN settings dialog, go to `Advanced`. Find the `Debug` option, set it to `true` and click `Apply` or `OK`.

Now every command you do with TortoiseSVN will first show a dialog with the command line TortoiseProc.exe was started with. That way you can easily figure out the command line you want.

After that, open the settings dialog again and set the `Debug` option back to `false`.